# Visual Studio 2013 adds EXEC prefix to makefile output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, makefile

If I use an external makefile to build a solution in Visual Studio 2013, the latter inserts a prefix 'EXEC' to every error line it meets in the output before placing it to the output window. As the result clicking on error lines doesn't lead to jumping to the source file, because another part of the Visual Studio now perceives 'EXEC' as a part of the file name and of course it cannot find such a file, because there is no file starting from 'EXEC :'.

You can easily test it. Create a makefile project, in the project settings in "Build Command Line" type

```
echo filename.cpp(76,41) error : 'xxx' was not declared in this scope
```

Then try to build the project. You will see this in the output window:

```
EXEC : filename.cpp(76,41) error : 'xxx' was not declared in this scope
```

Is there a way to get rid of 'EXEC : ' in the output window?

Comment: add in your first sed line, at the start of action command `s/^EXEC *: *//;`

Comment: You misunderstand. There is no EXEC in the output, there is nothing to filter out with sed. It's Visual Studio who adds EXEC to whatever is coming from stdout or stderr.

Comment: I've stopped reporting bugs about VS2013 since I don't want to do this all the day long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: this answer is incorrect - I'm not deleting it (at least for the moment) here because the comments attached led me to what I think is a more correct answer that I have posted separately.

---

It looks like your problem is caused by the character `':'` being in the command line.

I'm not sure why that character causes some special processing by VS, and I'm not sure if there are other characters that will cause similar behavior.  But in your specific example of:

```
echo filename.cpp(76,41) error : 'xxx' was not declared in this scope
```

if you remove the `':'` character:

```
echo filename.cpp(76,41) error  'xxx' was not declared in this scope
```

the Build Output window shows this:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: makefile-project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  filename.cpp(76,41) error  'xxx' was not declared in this scope
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

One way to get rid of the problem character from VS's makefile project configuration is to put your command into a batch file or nmake file and have the VS makefile project invoke the batch/nmake file with a simpler command.

---

Update:

This problem doesn't seem to occur with *any* command that contains a `':'` character.  For example, the following commands cause `EXEC` to be prepended:

```
echo error :
c:\util\unxutils\usr\local\wbin\echo error :
```

But the following do not:

```
echoargs error :
echo :
```

(`c:\util\unxutils\usr\local\wbin\echo` and `echoargs` are `.exe` files that echo their arguments)

So the trigger seems to be a combination of `echo` as the command and `error :` as the arguments.  I assume there might be other triggers, but anyone's guess is as good as mine.

Comment: The OP said that the line with ':' gave no problem though.

Comment: @harper: that's not how I read the question.  Also, the behavior I describe in the answer is what I see in Visual Studio. If the `':'` is in the command line then the line in the output window has an `EXEC` at the front of it; if the `':'` is removed from the command then non `EXEC` in the output window.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks! The error messages are now clickable. I found that I also can add a colon before "error" and it solves the problem too.

Comment: Ah, I see. The line with one ':' gave no problem, but the other with an additional ':' (probably at the wrong position).

Comment: Yes - I've updated the answer with the results of some more experiments.  The trigger seems oddly specific.

Comment: Echo is irrelevant. You can specify anything that fills in stdout/err as a build command. The result will be the same. I'm obviously not using echo for building :). Echo was an example to ease reproducing the problem.

Comment: I see from information in your original question that `echo` isn't necessary.  So in your original use case (`make` piped into `sed`) was the problem triggered by using redirection and pipes, and in the `echo` example it's triggered because VS 'knows' that `echo` dumps stuff to `stdout`?  Is that why `echoargs error :` doesn't trigger the problem (VS doesn't know anything about `echoargs`)?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with pipes, echos, seds, makes, makefiles, redirection, etc.

It's VS that inserts 'EXEC : ' to whatever is in stdout/err. VS has no idea (and of course shouldn't) where the contents of stdout/err is coming from.

Comment: Just a small C program that dumps it's arguments.  I was using it as a test point because I was wondering if the problem had something to do with `echo` being treated specially by VS, maybe because it's a builtin to `cmd.exe` instead of an external command.

Comment: I just have written a similar application. The result is still the same: VS adds 'EXEC : ' prefix.

Comment: @noxmetus: the discussion here has led to post a new answer - I think one should be unaccepted and eventually deleted.

Comment: I'm pretty much satisfied with your first answer. The question was: how to get rid of 'EXEC : '. You answered how: add a colon. Period. This being said in the rest of you answer and in the second answer you are just reiterating the obvious. An error or a warning message is three fields separated with colons. The first one is the source. If VS cannot find the source it adds 'EXEC : ' as the source. Q.E.D.

Comment: @noxmetus: it sure wasn't obvious to me!  I think the first answer is misleading.

Comment: Well, then just edit the first answer leaving only the answer "add a colon" and my explanation :).

Answer (score 1):

I think I've gotten a good enough, even if incomplete, idea of what's going on to be useful.

As you mentioned in comments to my previous misleading answer, the problem isn't in the command line being used - it's due to VS inspecting the output and adding the `EXEC` prefix in certain specific cases.

If the output line contains a sequence that looks like `"error :"` or `"warning :"` - fields in the line of output that would make VS think the line of output is a diagnostic, VS will prepend the line of output with `EXEC` if there's not already a `':'` character *preceding* that field.

For example, the following line will be prefixed with `EXEC :`:

```
filename error :
```

and this one won't:

```
filename: error :
```

It seems that VS wants to ensure that is there's a field indicating a diagnostic, that there's something resembling a filename field (with the fields delimited by `':'` characters.

So the bottom line is that when you are creating diagnostic output (or reformatting output to a VS-compatible format), make sure it at least follows the general format of:

```
filename : error/warning code :
```

followed by what appears to be arbitrary text (I'm not sure if subsequent `':'` characters are significant).

The first two `':'` characters are what appear to be important:

- a filename field (with optional line & column) followed by a `':'`
- a diagnostic code field (can say "error" or "warning" and probably other tokens) followed by a `':'`